# maxPageStateFieldLength ignored in web.config

Tags: asp.net

I've got a page with a large viewstate that appears to be tuncated during postbacks on one of our client's server. We will minimize this in the next release.

I'm trying the maxPageStateFieldLength page attribute in web.config, but it looks like this attribute is ignored.  Viewstate size is larger than the value in bytes placed in this attribute, so the viewstate should be chunked in multiple input fields, but the page is generated with a single input field.

server is 2003/IIS 6, using compression.

Naming the attribute with an uppercase M triggers an error, so i know that it is recognized (with lowercase m) but asp.net does no chunking.

It is working with the same application under VS 2005 using internal web server on my dev machine.

Any idea what might cause this attribute to be ignored?

Comment: forgot to specify this is asp.net 2.0

Comment: what value are your setting it to?

Comment: Value is: maxPageStateFieldLength="10240".  ViewSate size on this page is about 300Kb, so it should do some chunking.  I'm still investgating this

Comment: Web site is a web application project, precompiled using the web deployment project add-on.  I just found out that when the flag is set in web.config before precompilation, it works on the target machine.  Removing the flag once deployed does not remove chunking !  

if i precompile without the flag, i add the flag after deployment, this config change is not picked-up after application restart.

I'm wondering if the precompilation tool looks to this flag and generate a compiled page with chunking enabled or not.  This would explain this behavior.  I'll try to decompile to see if it's true

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This link](http://odetocode.com/Blogs/scott/archive/2006/02/24/3019.aspx) explain the behavior described in my last comment.  Precompilation to a non updatable web site hardcode some page parameter values in the assembly, like theme, and i just found out, viewstate chunking